# CSS3 Card Flip Glitch

Tags: html, css, animation, transition

I created an HTML flip card using CSS. However, when the card flips there is a flicker (as if it almost won't turn over fully). This glitch happens mainly when the cursor is moved directly in the center of the card.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```css
.card-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.card:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.back {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="card-box">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      Front
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      Back
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is a link to the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rogybear/tfcu3qkr/3/

Comment: apply the hover on the card-box instead and then target card element

Comment: That's it!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

added

```
.card-box:hover .card {
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
```

```css
.card-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.card-box:hover .card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.back {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="card-box">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      Front
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      Back
    </div>
  </div>
```